# Has anyone created a vertical UIToolBar? Or some sort of vertical menu with UIButtons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitoolbar

I am trying to created a vertical menu (on the left side of the screen) which I can display and hide using a gesture recognizer.

I have found a post similar to this which helped slightly, but all it did was rotate the UIToolBar to a vertical position without changing the width or position.

If anyone has succesfully created something similar to this and is willing to help I would greatly appreciate it!

Also, if anyone can point me in the right direction possibly to some sample code I would like that as well.

Comment: I am working on a 100% custom UIToolBar based on a UIView. It is in its very early stage but the idea is something similar to the Mac's dock that can be hidden if wanted. What I just did is to create a custom UIView and override its drawRect method. Inside that UIView I add UIButtons with the different actions I need (usually view transitions). Finally, using a gesture recognizer, I hide the bar if a tap occurs anywhere in the rest of the window.

Comment: Or you could build the toolbar in a .xib.  Just size and position the view as you want it, add the buttons, connect the buttons and the view, and set the view to hidden.  Then connect the gesture recognizer to the view's hidden property, or animate it on and off screen.  I've created one that's draggable and hide-able, if you want the code for that-- but I did all the view and button creation in IB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a `UIToolBar` by applying a 90 degree rotation transform, and then having all your icons rotated 90 degrees to match - you can change the width and position simply by adjusting the `UIToolBar` frame. However, you will need to create your own toolbar to do this rather than using the built-in one you get with a navigation controller.

Another option is simply to roll it yourself: this will allow you more customisation, so is perhaps the better option. There are a number of third-party implementations of varying types, some based off the current Facebook App side-bar, a good place to start looking is http://cocoacontrols.com - they are of varying quality.

On the other hand, it wouldn't be too difficult to roll your own, so that's a good option to consider.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finding something to work with from that site you referenced! I had never heard of that site before! It has tons of useful stuff!

I should probably "roll" my own but due to lack of time this will suffice. I just started developing for the iPhone about 5 months ago so I definitely could use the practice...